# Order Events in Fullcalendar by Start date and End Date

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I order events in fullCalendar first by start date?

Example:

- An event which starts first will show on top and then one which starts later will be later
- If two events have same the start date then, order them by end date
  i.e 
  an event which ends earlier will be shown first, followed by an event which ends later.

[Calendar Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDL9C.png)
[Events Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHBNq.png)

```
var args = jQuery.parseJSON(emCalendarArgs);
var Jobj = args.events;

// Setup FullCalendar

(function() {
  //var language = jQuery('#pg_lang').val();
  //alert(language+ 'dsfsd');
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  var language = langg;
  var mn_text, week_text, day_text, list_text;

  //alert(mn_text);
  var args = jQuery.parseJSON(emCalendarArgs);
  var Jobj = args.events;
  console.log(Jobj);
  jQuery('#events-full-calendar').fullCalendar({

    allDaySlot: false,
    editable: true,
    lang: 'he',
    handleWindowResize: true,
    eventOrder: 'start,end',
    header: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
      month: mn_text,
      week: week_text,
      day: day_text
    },
    eventLimit: {
      'month': 3, // adjust to 4 only for months
      'default': false // display all events for other views
    },
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    timeFormat: {
      agenda: 'H:mm{ - h:mm}'
    },
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    events: Jobj,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
  });
}());
```

Comment: Assuming we are not talking about agenda views, where the grid system makes all of this irrelevant: _"A Event Which start first Will show on top"_. This is already the default behaviour. _"If Two Events have same start date then order them by End Date i.e Event which ends earlier will be shown first and then Event which ends later."_ . There's no direct support for this. Your best option is to return them in the desired order in your event feed.

Comment: Event order still not changing on calendar.
I changed the order of the Event Feed how i want, But still the calendar is Showing the Events According to Start Date only , is there any changes required in fullcalendar.js also ?

Comment: which view type are you using? Actually from doing a bit of testing myself I can see that it does the opposite of what you want (in month view, at least) - in fact it appears to order them with the one that has the latest end date, first, and then in descending order from there. See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/14/. I can't see anything in the docs about how to change this, so probably you'd have to modify the fullCalendar source code, or submit a feature request to the maintainer to get it added as an option. This is done via Github, I believe.

Comment: Ok Thanks , I am Using Basic View for all the three Month , Day and Week but no luck .

Comment: Ah wait, I found it. It pays to read the docs properly. have a go with one of the options here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/ . If you get stuck, post your code and problem here.

Comment: I have already gone thourgh this document of fullcalendar . But this does not either change the order of events . I have tried to apply eventOrder in the js fiddle also , but it is not changing the result , I am adding my code

Comment: it's documented, so it should work. Most likely you're not using it correctly. I'll have a look at the code once you post it.

Comment: I have Added the code and also two screenshorts 'Display Calendar' showing how events are ordered in calendar and 'Events Order' showing how Events Order are Actually Coming in Feed after Applying Query .

Comment: I have used the Parameter eventOrder and tried in the Jsfiddle added by you here but here also its not working , the way i am including is              
eventOrder:'title' just above 'header' but its not working . Please look for my code as well and let me know what is wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I still need to read more carefully (and maybe so do you!). The eventOrder docs say it only applies to "events that have the same dates / times". So it won't work for your purpose. Apologies for wasting your time on this. Therefore my earlier comment stands:  you'd have to modify the fullCalendar source code, or submit a feature request to the maintainer to get it added as an option.

Comment: Okay , No problem i will go for fullcalendar source code feature request then.

Comment: I found a Solution to it ,for any one else looking for the solution to this ,i changed  function
compareSegs: function(seg1, seg2) {
  return seg1.eventStartMS - seg2.eventStartMS || // earlier events go first
   seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first
   seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)
   compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs);
 }

Comment: and what was the solution? I'm interested to know. Please post it as an answer if it would help others.

Comment: like I said, post that as an answer and then you get can upvotes for it, and then it's clear for others in future. And you are allowed to accept your own answer as well :-)

Comment: Ok thanks , i have added the Answer below

Answer (score 2):

I found a Solution to it. For any one else looking for the solution to this, I changed a function in fullcalendar.js:

```
compareSegs: function(seg1, seg2) { return seg1.eventStartMS - seg2.eventStartMS || // earlier events go first seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1) compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs); }
```

to :

```
compareSegs: function(seg1, seg2) {
        if(this.view.name=="basicWeek" || this.view.name=="month" || this.view.name=="basicDay"){ // ordering events by color in ListView
        return seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)
            compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs);
        }
        else{
            return seg1.eventStartMS - seg2.eventStartMS || // earlier events go first
                        seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first
                        seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)
                        compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs);
        }
    }
```

and used below code in fullcalendar function

```
eventOrder: 'start, end'
```

in my fullcalendar call