# EventOrder property of fullCalendar.io is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

```
eventOrder : 'state',
```

I have used this property of fullcalendar.io to sort my events. In all events are sorted properly at correct position but one event is not sorted. The reason behind this is that fullcalander.io will sort event on duration bases also.I am uploading the js  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqiltariq65/jso51pm6/130/) for example.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle or plnkr to reproduce your problem?

Comment: The root cause is duration.
FullCalendar decides that events with longer durations and earlier start times are sorted above other events.(source documentation).
I want that full calendar do not sort on duration.
Sorting done only on this basis
eventOrder : 'start,state,city',

Comment: Your approach should work. Please create a fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqiltariq65/jso51pm6/126/
This js fiddle
Same example

Comment: I required sorting like this in fiddle example
1)3 Meeting
2)1 Meeting
3)2 Meeting

Comment: If I understand you right. You want: 1) order all events by start date 2) Order all events with the same date by state 3) Order all events with same start date & state by city?

Comment: As I think you may have grasped, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/, the eventOrder settings that you give are only applied when two or more events have the same start time and duration. If you want to change this behaviour you'll have to modify the source code yourself. Alternatively you could submit a feature request to the maintainer and wait for them to implement full flexibility on sorting as an option. Actually though someone asked a similar thing a few days ago and managed to answer their own question - perhaps it will be helpful:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052484/order-events-in-fullcalendar-by-start-date-and-end-date . They were trying to implement a slightly different sorting rule, but it gives you a clue where in the source code this stuff is decided, so you could just remove any code which sorts by duration.

Comment: @lin yes but in my original code.
I have implemented the same situation in my fiddle.
Have you tried the fiddle?  Try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aqiltariq65/jso51pm6/130/). In this fiddle, 1Meeting should be above the 2Meeting as 1Meeting has less duration but it is shifted down due to less duration.

Comment: @ADyson can you give me the thread where a similar thing was asked few days ago.

Comment: @aqiltariq65 I did. The link is at the beginning of my last comment...